# Jquery image height and resize

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image that should be the height of the window minus 70px.

But it is not working only when I manually resize the window.

//jquery

```
$(document).ready(reSize);

$(window).resize(reSize);

function reSize(e) {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 70;

    $('.image').css("height", windowHeight);
}
```

//css

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: may be your selector is wrong. it might be `$('img')` instead. or your image does not have a class name `.image`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code pretty much works for me.

Try using the selector `$('img')` instead of `$('.image')` as it is what you are using in the css.

You do not need to use the css function here: `height()` works great, and you also do not have to define the height of `img` in the css.

```
function reSize() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 70;
    $('img').height(windowHeight);
}

$(document).ready(reSize);
$(window).resize(reSize);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wn63v6x8/

Comment: If you are using the tag name in `jQuery` selector you should define a `context` for not to apply operations for all `<img>` in the document if it is not your goal for sure.